# How to redirect to another page with a button?

Tags: html

trying to avoid JS as much as possible, so I was wondering if there was a way to get redirects by using a button? I've been searching and trying, but can't find a solution that works.

Structure:

```
main.py
static/
   templates/
      index.html
      404.html
   styles/
      index.css
```

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html")

app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML of 404.html, which has a button I want to redirect back to home

```
<div class = "btn-bot">
<button class="button" type="button" role="button" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Return</button>
</div>
```

Clicking the buttons and all that stuff works just fine, but it never does any action or redirecting. Console outputs nothing.

Comment: [Check it out](https://kanchanardj.medium.com/redirecting-to-another-page-with-button-click-in-python-flask-c112a2a2304c)

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal, you should use the `a` tag.

Example:

```html
<div class = "btn-bot">
    <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">
        <button class="button" type="button" role="button">Return</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, I just got the answer by another person, but this is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to change the button line to

```
<a href="/home"><button class="button" type="button" role="button">Return</button></a>
```

and in the Python file, just added /home as another route to the index